# How to measure the car battery charge with good precision

Tags: batteries, automotive, gauge, lead-acid

My goal is to replace the analog battery gauge in the dashboard - with a more accurate, digital gauge.

My first idea was to look for a specialized IC. I'm familiar with battery gauges for LiPo batteries like the STC3100IST, so I thought "probably there's something similar for lead-acid batteries, since they are used in nobreaks".

And indeed there was, like the [bq78412](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/bq78412.html) - but all hard to find, overwhelmingly complex. Also, they are designed to measure multiple cells, with current measuring features which for a car are of course not useful (think about installing a current sensing resistor...)

Then, my second choice was just to use an ADC after a voltage divider made with resistors to reduce from the 12-14V to hundreds of milivolts - giving a 10x margin to survive voltage spikes.

But this second choice seems almost too simplistic. Will it work? Will it survive the harsh environment a car is? Are there any feasible alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to measure battery state of charge (SOC), or just measure terminal voltage in a different way?

Comment: It's SOC, but the reading'll be fed to a uC, so I can do the translation there - If I just have the voltage with 3-digit precision it'll be fine.

Comment: That presumes a linear or near-linear relationship between SOC and terminal voltage, which you may find lacking when monitoring Pb-acid batteries.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law)  What is of more interest to you:  voltage or SOC?

Comment: @fceconel  Do you want to measure the battery, which starts the motor in the car?  If so, why do you need to know its SOC precisely?  Are you doing anything else with this battery, outside of normal car operation?

Comment: Most accurate lead acid battery SoC testers do an Interrogate and Response load test. This is related to the worst case cell in series and it's specific gravity and then scaling by the number of cells and capacity of each cell.

Comment: @DeanB SOC is more important, but it'd be nice if I could have both. Mainly, I want to detect two situations: (1) when the battery is approaching a too low charge while the car engine is off (for whatever reason - sitting idle for too long in the garage or the headlights were left on) and (2) when the battery is not recharging correctly with the engine on (if the alternator isn't working perfectly or the battery is old/defective) preferably before the battery gets too much discharged, so the driver could be warned in advance.

Comment: @NickAlexeev my answer to dean also answers some of the points you asked, for the others: yes, I want to measure the standard car battery; and no, I'm doing nothing more than is regularly done (i.e. supply the engine electric system, power the car lights, the car stereo, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need a sophisticated setup (like [bq78412](http://www.ti.com/product/bq78412)) for measuring the SoC of a starter battery in a car.  Your second approach with measuring the battery through a voltage is adequate.

The lead-acid batteries can be split into two (2) groups:

1. **Starter** batteries, such as the ones found in common cars and motorcycles.  These always operate high SoC under normal conditions.  They are discharged by the starter for just a few seconds.  That takes may be 5% of the charge.  Afterwards, they are recharged by the alternator in just a few minutes.  An important requirement for starter batteries is the ability to deliver high current.
2. **Deep cycle** batteries are designed to discharge down to 20%.  Probably, bq78412 was made with deep cycle batteries in mind.

If you know the battery capacity within 20%, you can still detect the faults, which you're describing (lights left on, defective alternator or battery).

P.S. This question have been up for a day, there are no responses, we've got use cases from @fceconel in his comments.  I feel that I can provide a systems-engineering answer.